# Generate unique url for every user who registers to your site

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing

Right, so I was working on developing a website(just a beginner though). I have stuck at this issue of generating a unique url for each user who registers on my site.
Now say my site is named, `www.mydomainname.com`. As of now every user has a profile which has the same url, regardless of the username, `www.mydomainname.com/myaccount.aspx`.
This is because I extract data for every user based on his username by sql queries. Now I want to remove that myaccount.aspx and add the username of the registered user to the url. This also helps in other users visiting your profile, just like youtube or facebook.
Routing might help me(not sure though), but any ideas or sample code or even shower knowledge of how to achieve this would be of great help.

Comment: Encrypt your userid appended with a token generated at sever end ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the asp.net Membership Provider you can include the user id in a querystring, the user id is a unique GUID value. It would be something like:

```
Guid userId = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
string url = string.Format("www.mydomainname.com/myaccount.aspx?user={0}", userId.ToString());
```

For example, this would give the url:

> www.mydomainname.com/myaccount.aspx?user=0CCAFADF-0BAE-4985-8073-1639985740BE

From this URL you can grab the `user` querystring value with:

```
string guid = Request.QueryString.Get("user");
```

Comment: Well this does ignite the bulb. But what if I'm not using the asp.net membership provider?

Comment: @GlBr Then use whatever other unique identifier you have for your users instead. If it isn't already a Guid, I'd recommend making it one.

Answer (score 0):

You could also implement routing as you have mentioned as one of the options:

```
 void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("MyAccount","Account/{username}", "~/myaccount.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: How to extract the data for that particular user, when viewing the page as other user?

Comment: You can get <% $RouteValue:username %>